# Using php laravel code: Leave the cell (exported excel) empty if an array is duplicate

Tags: php, excel, laravel, csv

I am using php laravel. I'm trying to export the data into excel `.csv` file with unique data or leaving the cell empty instead of duplicating the data. What filter should I use to do that? To be clear I will show some illustration
This is an example of the Excel View with the data from the array which is exported using php:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+
| Group  | First Name | Last Name |
+--------+------------+-----------+
| Group1 | John       | Doe       |
+--------+------------+-----------+
| Group1 | Jane       | Doe       |
+--------+------------+-----------+
| Group2 | John       | Smith     |
+--------+------------+-----------+
| Group2 | Jane       | Smith     |
+--------+------------+-----------+
```

This is an example of Excel View that I need. You can see that the duplicating groups are hidden:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+
| Group  | First Name | Last Name |
+--------+------------+-----------+
| Group1 | John       | Doe       |
+--------+------------+-----------+
|        | Jane       | Doe       |
+--------+------------+-----------+
| Group2 | John       | Smith     |
+--------+------------+-----------+
|        | Jane       | Smith     |
+--------+------------+-----------+
```

And this is the code that I've been using:

```
public function getDashboardBookingsReport2($account_alias, $group_alias){
    header       (...)

        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');


        fputcsv($file, array('Group Name', 'First Name', 'Last Name'));

        $table = (...)

        $rowed[] = array(
            $egroup->name,     // Group
            $user->first_name, // First Name
            $user->last_name,  // Last Name
                        );
                    }

                }
            }
                (...)

        $data = $rowed;
        uasort($data, function($a, $b) {
            return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
        });
        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
            fputcsv($file, $row);
        }

        exit();
    return Redirect::to( $group_alias.'/app/dash' );
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you asking. You don't want to write the first cell is the same while writing the PHP File?
If so how is even excel involved in this? You are just writing a file from PHP correct?

Comment: @dgorti I include excel there because that code exports as excel `.csv`. The diagram above is an example of an excel with duplicating group name

Comment: No it is not. Your code is not exporting anything as excel. It is exporting to a CSV that *can* be opened by excel. But csv is a general format and your code does not do anything with excel. SO there are no filters to be applied. 
You need to decide how you want to write the csv file.

Comment: @dgorti I'm telling you it is. All im asking is how to remove the duplicates because exporting it is already working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code just before `foreach ($data as $row)` and after `uasort($data, function($a, $b)`:

```
for($i = count($data) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    if($data[$i][0] === $data[$i - 1][0]) {
        $data[$i][0] = "";
    }
}
```